# Number guessing game in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, random

I'm currently stuck on a simple program which has a **Guess** and **Reset** button for guess a number from 1-100. The user is given 5 turns. My current issue is that I can't get my **Reset** button to correctly function. When it is pressed, rather than generating a new game entirely, it instead just generates a new number but when **Guess** is then pressed the original number that was generated is used again.

I'll include some code snippets where I feel I am making big logic errors.

So just my counter and initial random number variables and then the **Guess** and **Reset** button

```
       int counter = 0;
       int num = genRan();

   /////////////////////////////////////
        guessButton.setOnAction(e -> {

        int numToGuess = num;

        gameSetUp(guessField, counter, numToGuess);

    });

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    resetButton.setOnAction(e -> {

        System.out.println("Generating new game...");

        int newNum = genRan();
        int newCounter = 0;

        gameSetUp(guessField, newCounter, newNum);

    });
```

My random number generator.

```
public int genRan() {
        Random rand = new Random();

        int numToGuess = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;

        System.out.println("number is" + numToGuess);

        return numToGuess;
    }
```

And where I think it's all going wrong...

```
public void gameSetUp(TextField guessField, int counter, int num) {

    int numToGuess = num, maxGuesses = 5;

    try {
        if (counter != 5) {
            int guessNum = Integer.valueOf(guessField.getText());

            if (guessNum == numToGuess) {
                System.out.println("Correct!");
            } else if (guessNum < numToGuess) {
                counter++;
                System.out.println("You guessed " + guessNum + ", which was too low. " + (maxGuesses - counter)
                        + " guesses left!");
            } else if (guessNum > numToGuess) {
                counter++;
                System.out.println("You guessed " + guessNum + ", which was too high. " + (maxGuesses - counter)
                        + " guesses left!");
            }
        }

    } finally {
        if (counter == maxGuesses) {
            System.out.println("\nGame Over...");
        }
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate any help at all, thanks.

Comment: You may have your gameplay and gamesetup all in one method.  Game setup normally only handle the initial state of the game.

Comment: Your gamePlay code should be in the `guessButton's` `onAction`. Your gameSetup code should be in the `resetButton's` `onAction`.

Comment: You only assign local variables in the `gameSetUp`. You don't modify `counter` and `numToGuess` in any of the event handlers calling `gameSetUp` either. This means the state of the game never changes...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example app with the `Initial State` and the `Game Play State` separated.

```
import java.util.Random;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Sedrick
 */
public class JavaFXApplication47 extends Application {

    TextField guessField = new TextField();
    int counter = 0;
    int numberToGuess = -1;    

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {            

        guessField.setPromptText("Press New Game Button!");

        Button btnNewGame = new Button("New Game");        
        btnNewGame.setOnAction(actionEvent ->{
            gameSetup();
        });

        Button btnGuess = new Button("Guess");
        btnGuess.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
            gamePlay();
        });



        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(guessField, new HBox(btnNewGame, btnGuess));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        btnNewGame.requestFocus();
    }    


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


    public void gameSetup()
    {
        guessField.setPromptText("Enter your guess");//set guessField to zero
        counter = 0; //set counter to zero

        //set numberToGuess to a new random number
        Random random = new Random();
        numberToGuess = random.nextInt(100) + 1;
        System.out.println("Number to guess: " + numberToGuess);
    }

    public void gamePlay()
    {
        int guess = Integer.parseInt(guessField.getText());

        if(counter == 5)//Check it counter == 5
        {
            System.out.println("Game over! You lose!");
            guessField.setPromptText("Game over! You lose!");
            guessField.setText("");
        }
        else{
            if(guess == numberToGuess)
            {
                System.out.println("You win");
                guessField.setPromptText("Your guess of " + guess + " is correct! You win!");
                guessField.setText("");
            }
            else if(guess < numberToGuess)
            {
                System.out.println("You guessed to low");
                guessField.setPromptText("You guessed to low! Try again.");
                guessField.setText("");
                counter++;
            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("You guessed to high! Try again.");
                guessField.setPromptText("You guessed to high! Try again.");
                guessField.setText("");
                counter++;
            }         
        }        
    }
}
```